# shell script to close multiple independent processes, but logical dependent

Tags: bash, shell

I have a pair of executables 1)**code_A** and 2)**code_B**, they communicate using two *message_queues*, hence **code_A** and **code_B** both take a pair of message queue *key*s (key_t) as command line arguments called msgQ_key1 and msgQ_key2. Along with the two command line arguments, the **code_A** takes two more arguments called MAC and IP. It means as a complete set the application requires four parameters **MAC, IP, msgQ_key1 and msgQ_key2**.
Hence I have a file  which contains those parameters in a single line each separated by a space. 
Sometimes the file  may have multiple sets of parameters separated by a new line as shown below

1. 00:e0:4c:36:39:ec 10.180.6.164 9189 3488
2. 00:e0:4c:36:39:ed 10.180.6.165 5678 1234

so I have a to run two instances of the application (two pairs of code_A and code_B, in each pair code_A has something to print on stdout but code_B can run in the background)
Now I want to write a script file to read from the file , line by line, and for every line read open an instance of code_A and code_B in a separate terminal (it means for the above (the 2 lines) example there will be code_A_1, code_B_1 and code_A_2 and code_B_2), and if I want to close one instance, it should close the correct pair of code_A and code_B.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#make
gcc decisionTree.c -o code_B
gcc smu.c -o code_A
IFS=" "
while read MAC IP msgQ_key1 msgQ_key2 
do
        echo "$MAC $IP $msgQ_key1 $msgQ_key2"
        ./code_B $MSGQID1 $MSGQID2
        gnome-terminal -e ./code_A $MAC $IP $msgQ_key1 $msgQ_key2
done    < config.dat
```

Comment: Can not find the question mark.

Comment: So...  What problem do you need help with?  What result does that script produce and how should it be different?

Comment: sorry, the line-9 should be  **./code_B $msgQ_key1 $msgQ_key2**.  I have clearly mentioned in the second paragraph that, for what I want to write a script, I wrote the above given script but it isn't working, I was expecting it to open two new terminals and run two instances of code_A but it isn't and if I check with ps -a  it is showing only one code_B current process nothing else (I was expecting two code_A and two code_B). And if I want to close one pair (code_A_1, code_B_1 is pair1) how do i do it